# How to create news ticker XML file in Joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5, news-ticker

I got this extensions and all I want to know is how I am able to get the news ticker from XML file and how should I create this file?

I tried this one and it is not working.

XML file

http://www.4shared.com/document/uNJ9sdmD/newsxml.html

Extension link

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/6633?qh=YToxMDp7aTowO3M6NDoibmV3cyI7aToxO3M6MzoibmV3IjtpOjI7czo3OiJuZXduZXNzIjtpOjM7czo1OiInbmV3cyI7aTo0O3M6NToibmV3J3MiO2k6NTtzOjY6Im5ld2VseSI7aTo2O3M6NToibmV3cyciO2k6NztzOjY6Im5ld3MnLCI7aTo4O3M6NjoiJ25ldycsIjtpOjk7czo2OiInbmV3cyciO30%3D

Answer (score 0):

First create the XML file and insert it in the correct directory
/modules/mod_highlighter_gk4/xml --> this is where you need to insert the file.
You can find a sample XML file named Sample on that folder which tells you exactly how to format you XML file. It's something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

    <highlighter>    

        <item>

        <title>Title 1</title>

            <desc>Item description 1</desc>

            <link>http://item1.title.com</link>  

        </item>

<item>

        <title>Title 1</title>

            <desc>Item description 1</desc>

            <link>http://item1.title.com</link>  

        </item>
```

On the module itself first make sure you select the XML file on the "data source".
Then on the XML File option put the name of the XML File you created and it should work.

You can find more info from their website as well.
http://www.gavick.com/forums/highlighter.html

Comment: Thanks alot man I was hopeless b4 ur help now ill keep going trying and learning THANKS ALOT my friend :)